# Calculate and plot Heatmap in Python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, heatmap, divide

I want to divide the following matrix by 60 (converting it to seconds) and then plot a `heatmap` to see the density.

```
        Zone1   Zone2   Zone3   Zone4
2016-05-13_2    71  0   182 36
2016-05-14_3    94  0   0   68
2016-05-14_4    5   0   50  29
2016-05-17_5    0   101 0   36
2016-05-18_10   0   120 0   106
2016-05-18_11   62  0   784 3668
2016-05-18_12   0   330 0   19
```

I had to convert it to list values and then divide by 60

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.plotly as py

df2=(df.values/60)
df3=list(df2)
py.iplot(df3, filename='basic-heatmap')

PlotlyError: The `figure_or_data` positional argument must be either `dict`-like or `list`-like.
```

Please let me know where it went wrong

Comment: Isn't it `df3=list(df2)` instead of  `df3=list(df3)` ?

Comment: Yes.. its a typo. Edited it

Comment: your df3 is actually a list of numpy arrays.  you might want to try `df3 = df2.to_dict('dict')` or `df3 = df2.to_dict('list')`. (I can't say for sure b/c I don't know exactly what plotly is looking for there.)   you could also use the seaborn package to generate a heatmap directly from the dataframe instead of converting to a list or dict.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cufflinks, a library for easy interactive Pandas charting with Plotly.
Details please check here
https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/